# How does Bio.PDB identify hetero-residues?

Tags: structure, biopython, pdb

I'm wondering how Bio.PDB identifies a residue as a hetero-residue. 
I know that the residue.id method returns a tuple in which the first item is the hetero flag, the second one is the residue identifier (number) and the third one is the insertion code.

But how does the internal code decide what to put in the hetero flag field? Does it check whether the atoms in the residue are HETATM records vs. ATOM records?

Or does it check the atom names in each residue and compare it to some set of hetero-atoms?

The reason I ask is because in 4MDH chain B, the first residue in the coordinates section is ACE (acetyl). It has only C and O atoms, and the PDB file lists it as a HETATM. But when the residue.id for this residue is (' ', 0, ' ').

Here is my code:

```
>>> from Bio.PDB.mmtf import MMTFParser
>>> structure = MMTFParser.get_structure_from_url('4mdh')
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/StructureBuilder.py:89: PDBConstructionWarning: WARNING: Chain A is discontinuous at line 0.
  PDBConstructionWarning)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/StructureBuilder.py:89: PDBConstructionWarning: WARNING: Chain B is discontinuous at line 0.
  PDBConstructionWarning)
>>> chain = [c for c in structure.get_chains() if c.get_id() == 'B'][0]
>>> residue0 = [r for r in chain.get_residues() if r.id[1] == 0][0]
>>> residue0.id
(' ', 0, ' ')
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: It's not BioPython but the mmtf library which does the interpretation.

---

From the [source code](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/mmtf/DefaultParser.py):

```
self.structure_bulder.init_residue(group_name, self.this_type,
                                   group_number, insertion_code)
```

Here the residue is created. The 2nd parameter (`self.this_type`) is the `field`/`hetero flag` in [init_residue](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/StructureBuilder.py)

```
def init_residue(self, resname, field, resseq, icode):
    """Create a new Residue object.
    Arguments:
     - resname - string, e.g. "ASN"
     - field - hetero flag, "W" for waters, "H" for hetero residues, otherwise blank.
```

In the `mmtfParser` `this_type` is set for the whole chain in `set_chain_info`.

If you import the same sequence with `mmtf`, you can see that chain 0 and 1 are considered to be polymers which is interpreted as a 'regular` atom by BioPython. That makes sense since the acetate group is bound to the peptide chain.

```
from mmtf import fetch
decoded_data = fetch("4mdh")
print(decoded_data.entity_list)

[{'chainIndexList': [0, 1],
  'description': 'CYTOPLASMIC MALATE DEHYDROGENASE',
  'sequence': 'XSE...SSA',
  'type': 'polymer'},
 {'chainIndexList': [2, 4],
  'description': 'SULFATE ION',
  'sequence': '',
  'type': 'non-polymer'},
 {'chainIndexList': [3, 5],
  'description': 'NICOTINAMIDE-ADENINE-DINUCLEOTIDE',
  'sequence': '',
  'type': 'non-polymer'},
 {'chainIndexList': [6, 7],
  'description': 'water',
  'sequence': '',
  'type': 'water'}]
```

---

Note you can access models, chains and residues in BioPython by indexes, e.g.
`structure[0]['B'][0]` would give you the same atom as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

not sure that **MMTF files**  are widely used (https://mmtf.rcsb.org/faq.html)

if you use the `Bio.PDB.PDBParser` instead , the flag is set here

[https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/PDBParser.py#L193`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/PDBParser.py#L193)

```
  if record_type == "HETATM":  # hetero atom flag
      if resname == "HOH" or resname == "WAT":
          etero_flag = "W"
       else:
          hetero_flag = "H"
  else:
      hetero_flag = " "
  residue_id = (hetero_flag, resseq, icode)
```

given above `record_type = line[0:6]`

and then in : https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/StructureBuilder.py#L107 :

```
....
....

 def init_residue(self, resname, field, resseq, icode):
        """Create a new Residue object.

        Arguments:
         - resname - string, e.g. "ASN"
         - field - hetero flag, "W" for waters, "H" for
           hetero residues, otherwise blank.
         - resseq - int, sequence identifier
         - icode - string, insertion code

        """
        if field != " ":
            if field == "H":
                # The hetero field consists of H_ + the residue name (e.g. H_FUC)
                field = "H_" + resname
        res_id = (field, resseq, icode)
......
......
```